# T4 Relative Path Referencing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, t4

I'm using T4 to transform an h file from our embedded library into a C# file. This works fine, but I would like to provide relative reference to the file in question. So far this is all I've been able to come up with:

```
s = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.ResolvePath("thisFile.tt")) + @"\..\foo\bar.h";
```

It would be nice if I could include bar.h in the project and change the build action to "None" and then simplify:

```
s = Host.ResolvePath("bar.h");
```

But this throws an error and as far as I can tell you can only ResolvePath for files in the same directory as the T4 script.

Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Since bar.h is in a different folder, you need to give it the relative path. So you would do

```
s = Host.ResolvePath(@"..\foo\bar.h");
```

The answer can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg604090(v=vs.100).aspx

> To find the full path of a file relative to the text template, use
>   this.Host.ResolvePath().